# Is it possible to host multiple websites on one bucket on Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, web-hosting, bucket

Which is a better way to host multiple websites, all of them being static? Some are WordPress. 
Should I create different buckets for all or host all on a single bucket itself? Please let me know how can I host it on a single bucket.

Comment: You can host all of them in the same Storage Bucket keeping them in different folders or create a Bucket for each site.
I found this guide that you can have a look at on how to host a static web on Cloud Storage https://geekflare.com/cloud-storage-static-website

You can also make use of Google Cloud Launcher to easily deploy a Wordpress: https://cloud.google.com/launcher/docs

Comment: Also note that the GCS cost is based on data stored, not on the number of buckets so this would come down to preference

Answer (score 2):

Following the official documentation for [hosting a static website](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website) on Google Cloud Storage, you'll have to point a domain to the resource you want to serve, i.e www.example.com. You need to create a bucket with that name, so you'll need one bucket per domain.

Good thing is that you can create as many bucket as you want for no extra charge, as per [Quotas & Limits](https://cloud.google.com/storage/quotas).

Last thing I'd like to point out is that Wordpress actually isn't a static website. It's built in PHP which won't execute on Storage. There are [plugins](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/simply-static/) though that can generate a static website from your wordpress (or you could use [App Engine Flexible](https://cloud.google.com/php/tutorials/wordpress-app-engine-flexible)).